# как отсортировать многомерный массив по ключу

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка, callback

Как отсортировать массив по значению с ключем `y`. Если в элементе несколько массивов с таким ключем - берем минимальное значение.

```
$list = array(
    'a' => array(
        'v' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 9,  'z' => 3),
        'f' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 9,  'z' => 3)
    ),
    'b' => array(
        'v' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 1,  'z' => 3),
        'f' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 11, 'z' => 3)
    ),
    'c' => array(
        'v' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 9,  'z' => 3),
        'f' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 9,  'z' => 3)
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'v' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 22, 'z' => 3),
        'f' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 2,  'z' => 3)
    ),
    'e' => array(
        'v' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 92, 'z' => 3),
        'f' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 9,  'z' => 3)
    ),
    'f' => array(
        'v' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 2,  'z' => 3),
        'f' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 21, 'z' => 3)
    ),
    'g' => array(
        'v' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 12, 'z' => 3),
        'f' => array('x' => 1, 'y' => 1,  'z' => 3)
    ),
);
```

Comment: мы должны догадаться сами, каким вы себе представляете в данном случае результат сортировки?

Comment: @teran написано же по ключу y, автор ваш массив и так отсортирован по ключу y

Comment: наверно @teran прав стоило указать ожидаемый результат, b,g,f,d,a,c,e

Comment: @aleksey7 вы сам принцип сортировки можете написать? по минимальному из `v[y]` и `f[y]` что ли?

Comment: v,f не имеет значения эти ключи динамичны и их может быть больше двух, имеет значения только ключ 'у' который в свою очередь тоже динамичен может быть и string и init по которому нужно отсортировать a,b,c,d,e,f,g

Comment: ладно сдаюсь. у вас там внутри `a,b,c,d,e,...`  два элемента, у каждого из которых есть ключ `y`

Comment: @teran я вроде добился нужного результата но хотелось бы знать как это делается более профессионально [вот мой вариант](http://ix.io/Ezl)

Comment: @aleksey в вашем варианте значения `y` одинаковые. здесь же в вопросе они разные, поэтому у меня и были вопросы о принципе сортировки, на которые вы так и не ответили.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сортировать массивы по собственным критериям в PHP есть три функции

- [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) - сортировка без учета ключей (результат - неассоциативный массив)
- [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uasort.php) - сортировка с учетом ключей (соответствие ключ-значение сохраняется, меняются местами значения в зависимости от результатов вызова функции с значениями массива)
- [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uksort.php) - похоже на предыдущую функцию, но функция вызывается с значениями ключей.

Обратите внимание: Сортировка происходит "на месте" прямо в массиве, который передается первым аргументом (передается ссылка).

В вашем случае нужна функция `uasort()`. Остается только написать функцию сравнения.

```
// $list = ...
$res = uasort($list, function($a, $b) {
    $get_y = function ($x) { 
        return min( // берем минимальное значение (сделано предположение
                    // из приведенного примера)
            array_map(
                function($row) {
                    return $row['y']; // берем только значения поля 'y'
                },
                array_filter($x, function($row) {
                    //берем только "строки" в которых есть ключ 'y'
                    return isset($row['y']);
                })
            )
        );
    };
    $a_weight = $get_y($a);
    $b_weight = $get_y($b);
    if (is_int($a_weight) && is_int($b_weight)) {
        return $a_weight - $b_weight;
    }
    return strcmp($a_weight, $b_weight);
});
```

В результате получаем массив с порядком ключей `g, b, d, f, a, c, e`. Перестановки `g` - `b` и `d` - `f` происходит потому что php не "обещает" порядок значений, имеющих одинаковые критерии сравнения.

**Дополнено** Можно написать немного короче (будет работать в PHP 5.5+)

```
// $list = ...
$res = uasort($list, function($a, $b) {
    $a_weight = min(array_column($a, 'y'));
    $b_weight = min(array_column($b, 'y'));
    if (is_int($a_weight) && is_int($b_weight)) {
        return $a_weight - $b_weight;
    }
    return strcmp($a_weight, $b_weight);
});
```

Comment: там автор в комментах выкладывал свой код.  у него в примере там все значения y одинаковы внутри одного элемента. Так что вероятно предположение про минимальный не верно, а тут просто кривой пример в вопросе. поэтому и не объяснено ничего про критерии сортировки.

Comment: зы: map&filter => array_column?или он в случае отсутствия null возвращает?

Comment: Насчет предположения вы правы - может быть что оно не верно. Изменится вопрос - изменю ответ (основа-то не меняется). Насчет array_column - я тоже подумал что он вернет что-то в случае отсутствия ключа, проверил - пропускает такие строки. Спасибо за идею